# Proving Schwartz-lemma-like inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show for homework that if $D(0,R)$ is the open disc of radius $R$ centered at $0$ in the complex plane and $f:D(0,R) \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $|f(z)| \le M$ for some $M>0$, then
$$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{M^2-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}\right| \le \frac{|z|}{MR}$$
using the Schwartz lemma, which says that if $f:D(0,1) \to D(0,1)$ is holomorphic and $f(0)=0$ then $|f(z)| \le |z|$. I can see that we're generally going to have the left side be equal to 0 if we plug in zero, unless $\overline{f(0)}f(0)=M^2$, and I think I proved a variant of the Schwartz lemma where if $f:D(0,R) \to D(0,M)$ satisfies the other hypotheses, then
$$|f(z)| \le \frac{M|z|}{R}$$
but I'm not really sure where to go from there, and I've been stuck for a while. Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 0):

hint: Use Schwartz lemma on a composition of two functions.

$g(z) = \frac{1}{M}f(Rz)$ and

$h(z) = \frac{\frac{f(0)}{M} - z}{1 - \overline{\frac{f(0)}{M}}z}$ = $\Psi_{f(0) / M}$ (if you use that notation)

Comment: Isn't it possible that $f(Rz)$ is not defined? For example if $R=3$ and $z=2$, then $6 \notin D(0,3)$ so $f(Rz)=f(6)$ is not defined. Unless you meant $f(z/R)$, which would make more sense I think.

Comment: Maybe. I guess I didn't work it out all the way, but I think I want $g: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ so that it works with Schwartz lemma. But you might be right.

Comment: I ended up splitting it into cases depending on whether $R$ is greater than or less than 1.